# Is taking whey protein before a workout bad?

Tags: supplements, protein-shakes

Friends have told me that I should consume whey protein shake before *and* after workout. They said this would be effective for *building up muscles*. However, I have read from a website that I should avoid taking whey protein before workout.

Quoted from the article on the [website](http://ogglog.com/health/nutrition/whey-protein-dangers-side-effects-benefits-and-reviews/):

> You can have this power drink in the morning, as a snack, in between
>   meals, with meals, before going to sleep, or after a workout, **but
>   not before or during a workout**.

Is taking whey protein before a workout bad? What is the reason for avoiding to take whey protein before a workout?

Comment: Well it depends on your workout goals. What are they?

Comment: @Bee I intend to bulk up my muscle size through lifting weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least part of what you quote (the advice against taking protein during a workout) is opposite from advice given by the NSCA (emphasis mine):

> It is also best advised to consume 
>   carbohydrate and protein with fluid *during* exercise and/or
>   immediately post exercise.

This is from [*Recovery Nutrition for Athletes*](http://athletics.macalester.edu/custompages/Deno_Videos/nutrition/recovery_nutrition.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

If you have an intense workout ahead of you, it is a good idea to ingest whey protein before a workout. Whey protein contains a high amount of branches amino acids which help to preserve muscle supplies of glycogen, meaning you can work out for longer at a higher intensity and also increases muscle synthesis for several hours after the workout has been completed.
Therefore, this whey protein can help speed up the recovery process and reduce high levels of muscle soreness.
If you want to consume post-workout protein as well, ensure to consume protein with a relatively high amount of carbohydrates to repair muscle damage and tissue breakdown and encourage muscle recovery and healing